# trigger click on next tab in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger click on next tab in jQuery, I have tried below code but not working, TIA.

```js
var c = $('ul#tabs li').length;
var selected = parseInt($('ul#tabs li.active').index())+1;
if (c != selected) {
  $("ul#tabs li:nth-child(" + selected + ")").click();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="mytabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Personal" aria-expanded="false">Personal</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Business">Business</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Documents" aria-expanded="true">Documents</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#References">References</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#OrderDelivery">Order &amp; Delivery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `click on next tab`-> automatic click?

Comment: you're adding 1 -- you should try adding 2

Comment: based on some condition in jquery

Comment: why downvoting me ???/

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit unclear as to what's not working, but the simplified code below is all that's required to get current tab and next tab:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let currentTab = $('ul#tabs li.active');
  let nextTab = currentTab.next();

  // Once you have the tab, click it (clicking after 2 seconds to demonstrate)
  setTimeout(function() { nextTab.find("a").get(0).click()}, 2000);

  // If you need to do things when a tab is clicked, create an event handler
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(event) {
    // Do something when a tab is clicked
    // For example: Remove active class, and add it to active element
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').parent().removeClass("active");

    // Add active class to clicked li
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: green !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Personal" aria-expanded="false">Personal</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Business">Business</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Documents" aria-expanded="true">Documents</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#References">References</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#OrderDelivery">Order &amp; Delivery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @SunilKumar, then call `.click()` where ever you want. Again your question is unclear. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Dude, _what's_ not working about it? Are you getting errors? What behavior are you experiencing or not experiencing? You have to be more specific.

Comment: that is the issue i am not getting any error on browser console and next tab is also not clicked, don't know why....

Comment: even when i write "$("ul#tabs li:nth-child(2)").click();  " directly on console neither getting any error nor tab clicked..

Comment: @SunilKumar, what does that mean? Did my answer help solve your problem?